# Display fields base on grouped views row count

Tags: views

I'm creating a view that return grouped rows. Depend on the rows count under each group, I want to show different fields.

For example,

Group 1

- row 1
- row 2
- row 3

Group 2

- row 1
- row 2
- row 3
- row 4

Group 3

- row 1
- row 2
- row 3
- row 4
- row 5

Let's say if I have limited space then for Group 1, I want to show full text for all 3 rows. For Group 2, I want to show full text for the rows 1 & row 2 then trimmed text for the row 3 & 4. For Group 3, I only want full text for row 1 then trimmed text for the rest.

In Views advanced setting Theme:Information **Style template** print rows and **Row style template** print fields. In **Row style template**, if I know which row am I printing and how many rows in that group then I know which fields to display. For example, If I'm printing row 2 in the group of 5 then I know I need to display trimmed text field.

So my question is how can I know that in **Row style template**?

Thank you!